# createStatement method in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I have learned that Connection is an interface and we can define only method definition in interface.
  So how does this work:

....

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

....

How does this method create a Statement object and return it?

Answer (score 1):

Because a *concrete* implementation of the `Connection` interface is been returned when you called `getConnection()`. The interface just definies the method signatures. The concrete implementation contains the method implementations.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
System.out.println(connection.getClass().getName()); // That's the name of the concrete implementation.
```

It's the JDBC driver which contains those concrete implementations. The JDBC API enables you to write Java code independent of the specific database server used. Whenever you switch of DB, you just have to switch the JDBC driver (and possibly also change the SQL statements whenever they contain DB-server specific SQL language, but not the Java code).

Comment: You mean to say its Database Specific Class that perform implementations like "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" in case of Oracle.

Comment: Yes, the JDBC driver implements `java.sql.Driver`. The `Class#forName()` loads them by name which cause them to register themselves with `DriverManager#registerDriver()` inside a static initializer. the `DriverManager#getConnection()` in turn tests for every registered driver if `Driver#acceptsURL()` returns `true` for the given URL and then calls `Driver#connect()` on the driver which will then return the concrete `Connection` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this eg. 
The concept is similar to this eg.

```
public interface Human
{
public void run();
}

public class Man implements Human
{
public void run()
{
System.out.println("Man");
}
}

public class Main
{
public static void main(String s)
{
Human h= new Man();
h.run();
}
}
```

The output for this program will be `Man`.

Now comparing this with your problem.

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)`,
con doesn't point to connection object because it is an interface, it points to some class which has definately inherited `Connection` interface.

Now when you do this

`Statement stmt = con.createStatement();`

It does not call `Connection` interface method, it calls con actual refered method.
So you don't even know what it will return plus stmt will definately point to class which
has inherited `Statement` interface.